# restricting or preventing method implementation

Tags: java, methods, readonly-attribute

I have a scenario where I call a particular method  at multiple parts in my code.Now I need this method to be not implemented or the lines within this code not be executed for a particular condition ( like example a ON/OFF switch). I can add a if...else , everywhere where I am calling that method. but is there any other way to do it in java . maybe at method level?

As I mentioned don't want to add my if ..else everywhere where I call the method.
Adding example below:

```
public class Example {
static boolean readOnly = true;

public static  void getWorkDone() {
    System.out.println("I am working to get it done!!");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (readOnly == true)
        Example.getWorkDone();

}

public void anotherMethod1() {
    if (readOnly == false)
        Example.getWorkDone();
}

public void anotherMethod2() {
    if (readOnly == true)
        Example.getWorkDone();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Obviously it's an if/else you want however you wouldn't put it in multiple places... Depending on the complexity of your method you add the conditional to the method itself or wrap it in another method which performs the conditional and delegates to the existing method if "switched on", and call that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Make your method final and add some kind if configuration in it.

```
public final void doSomething() {
   if (switchedOn) return;
   // rest if the code. 
}
```

By making in final you make that none override the method from the classes that extend it.

By returning in the function you make sure that when some condition exists, nothing else happens

Comment: Athanasios Kataras Thank you, I think this seems reasonable.Will check this option and see.

Answer (score 0):

You said you can do it with an if else clause.  But if the could call the method, couldn't they also change the flag.

You could use `access restrictions` to make the method `unaccessible` to some.

You could also put the method in a `private inner class` and make it available via an instantiation of that class.  When you are done with the method, get rid of the instance.  If it is private, no one should be able to invoke it.  But the same is true for a private method too.

```
public class MainClass {
   String msg = "Hello, World!";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MainClass a = new MainClass();
      a.start();
   }
   public void start() {
      MyClass pvtClass = new MyClass();
      System.out.println(pvtClass.getMsg());
   }

   private class MyClass {

      private String getMsg() {
         return msg;
      }
   }
}
```

But as far as I know, you can't unload a method.

Comment: May I ask to know what do you mean by "can't unload a method" ?

Comment: Even Java lets you load classes and their methods via reflection.  Other languages allow the user to manipulate the symbol table and add or remove methods.  I was using it describe separating a method from its enclosing class.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification , that makes sense.